# Chrome and Safari table cell different height?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a simple table layout https://play.tailwindcss.com/Obrn65pCQN
The problem is that it looks different in Chrome and Safari. In Chrome it looks as expected, when table cell has full height. How can I fix it?

```
<table class="bg-gray-200">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="h-32 w-16"></td>
      <td class="bg-blue-200 bg-clip-content p-4 border border-red-600"><span class="inline-block bg-green-400">some content</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug about `background-clip: content-box` for Safari. You can use a gradient background to create same effect.

```css
.my-cell {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(59, 130, 246, 0.5), rgba(59, 130, 246, 0.5)) 50% 50% / calc(100% - 2rem) calc(100% - 2rem) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.2/tailwind.min.css"/>

<table class="bg-gray-200">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="h-32 w-16"></td>
      <td class="my-cell p-4 border border-red-600"><span class="inline-block bg-green-400">some content</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```